# Sorting a QListWidget using sortItems()

Tags: qt, sorting, qlistwidget

I have issues while using sortItems() on a QListWidget. Here is what happens:

Changes this:

A
z
d
C
E
o
I

to this:

A
C
I
d
e
o
z

But i want it to be:

A
C
d
e
I
o
z

Any way to change to make it sort like that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

QListWidget uses the DisplayRole (the item's text) for sorting and calls
QString::localeAwareCompare on them. To override the default, you can either change the locale used (see [QLocale](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale.html)) or have your own QListWidgetItem subclass reimplementing [QListWidgetItem::operator<](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidgetitem.html#operator-lt) and let it do the comparison you want.

For anything more advanced, I'd suggest to have a look at [QListView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html), which you could combine either with your own model implementation or the convenience models [QStandardItemModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html) or [QStringListModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlistmodel.html) (the latter could be the most simple and elegant solution in your case). For sorting, you would then put a [QSortFilterProxyModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html) in between the actual model and the view.

Comment: Can you show me a small example of how to do it with QLocale?