# Sorting QListWidget Items (c++)

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QlistWidget` with items as below,

```
item 1, item 2, item 3, ... , item 11, item 12, item 13
```

and I want to sort them in **Descending** order

```
item 13
item 12
item 11
item 10
item 9
item 8
item 7
item 6
item 5
item 4
item 3
item 2 
item 1
```

but `Qt::DescendingOrder`gives me:

```
item 9
item 8
item 6
item 5
item 4
item 3
item 2
item 13
item 12
item 11
item 10
item 1
```

are there any alternatives to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to solve this problem is to define a *custom order* on the items.

Create a class `MyListWidgetItem` which inherits `QListWidgetItem` and use that class instead of the base class to populate your list.
Then **overload the `MyListWidgetItem::operator <`**.
The simplest way to define the `operator<` is to parse the item's text.
The better way is to keep the number in a private field (e.g., `int MyListWidgetItem::index`) and use that field:

```
bool MyListWidgetItem::operator <(const QListWidgetItem& other) const
{
   // TODO: make sure that `other` is actually a MyListWidgetItem
   return this->index < static_cast<const MyListWidgetItem&>(other).index;
}
```

You should also use that field to generate the item's text on demand (reduce redundancy):

```
QVariant MyListWidgetItem::data(int role)
{
    switch (role) {
    case Qt::DisplayRole:
       return QString("Item %1").arg(index);
    default:
       return QVariant();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You get what you got due to the **string** `"item 10"` longer than the **string** `"item 1"`, but char `"item 10"[5] < "item 2"[5]`, so `"item 10" < "item 2"` even it is longer. There is compare of chars - not numbers.

So, you can create your own [compare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8494174/6547185) where you have to split the item name by spaces then convert string to number and then compare each part.

Or, you can create item names with [formatting](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg). For example by adding some space before number `QString("item %1").arg(i,3)`, you got:

```
item 11
item 10
item  2
item  1
```